# Upload two files and an object are failing with error 415

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, httprequest

I am trying to consume an http rest call that takes input of two files a dto

```
@RequestMapping(name = "/my/endpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody
    EndpointDto createEndpoint(@RequestBody MultipartFile requestFile, @RequestBody MultipartFile responseFile,
                               @RequestBody MyDto myDto){
        return endpointService.createEndpoint(requestFile, responseFile, myDto);
    }
```

I received the following error:

```
    org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: 
Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarylq2UHYfBi0nAsRo7;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

I consume the endpoint through swagger.
I think that the problem lies in the way I handle the input fields but I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Your annotations say: the body is a multipartFile, no it's a MyDto ... Define one type that represents the data as it is send by the client

Comment: I have removed the consumes multi part attribute and also I get the same problem

Comment: Could you please share you multipart configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/documents")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<DocumentDTO> createDocument(@RequestPart String document, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws URISyntaxException {

    DocumentDTO documentDTO = convertStringToDTO(document);

    DocumentDTO result = documentService.save(documentDTO, file);
    return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/documents/" + result.getId()))
        .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
        .body(result);
}

// com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
private DocumentDTO convertStringToDTO(String document) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    DocumentDTO documentDTO = null;
    try {
        documentDTO = objectMapper.readValue(document, DocumentDTO.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("DocumentString to JSON", e);
    }
    return documentDTO;
}
```

You have to send the data in form-data format from front-end with key as a file containing bytes and document JSON object.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the controller parameter as below

```
@RequestMapping(name = "/my/endpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<EndpointDTO> createEndpoint(
   @RequestPart(value = "file1") MultipartFile filea, 
   @RequestPart(value = "file2") MultipartFile fileb, 
   @RequestPart MyDto myDto){
    return endpointService.createEndpoint(filea, fileb, myDto);
}
```

You can get the files and DTO values using **@RequestPart**.

You can test above API using following curl

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -F "myDto=@body;type=application/json" -F "file1=@file1.txt" -F "file2=@file2.txt" -X POST http://<path>/my/endpoint
```

**Note:** Here I'm using 'body' file to pass the payload and file1.txt & file2.txt to pass the MultipartFile. Hope you are familiar with the curl command and understand it.

Comment: Your answer is more descriptive, however. I believe that "@RequestPart" annotation is not going to work with a given Dto. or at least it didn't work with me